# Thelia PHP installation admin folder missing

Tags: php

I am trying to install this E-Commerce framework [Thelia2](http://thelia.net)

But seems that after installation, the /web/admin folder was not created as expected.

I am guessing it is a permission problem, so I tried to give php permission to the folder

```
chown apache:apache path/to/thelia2
chmod 755 path/to/thelia2
```

but still not working.

Can anyone help?

error logs as below:

```
1: WARNING [Thelia.php:loadTranslation()] {287} 2014-09-05 13:23:06: loadTranslation: missing /var/www/html/thelia2/local/modules/TheliaDebugBar/I18n/backOffice/default directory
2: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:copyAssets()] {84} 2014-09-05 13:23:07: Copying assets from /var/www/html/thelia2/templates/frontOffice/default/assets to /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0.tmp
3: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {306} 2014-09-05 13:23:07: Asset destination full path: /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/css/7428519.css
4: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {313} 2014-09-05 13:23:07: Writing asset to /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/css
5: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {306} 2014-09-05 13:23:07: Asset destination full path: /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/img/857cfe8.ico
6: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {313} 2014-09-05 13:23:07: Writing asset to /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/img
7: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {306} 2014-09-05 13:23:07: Asset destination full path: /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/img/3aa5d01.png
8: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {313} 2014-09-05 13:23:07: Writing asset to /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/img
9: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {306} 2014-09-05 13:23:07: Asset destination full path: /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/img/888f132.gif
10: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {313} 2014-09-05 13:23:07: Writing asset to /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/img
11: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {306} 2014-09-05 13:23:07: Asset destination full path: /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/img/carousel/5725ca1.jpg
12: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {313} 2014-09-05 13:23:07: Writing asset to /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/img/carousel
13: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {306} 2014-09-05 13:23:07: Asset destination full path: /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/img/carousel/538cd94.jpg
14: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {313} 2014-09-05 13:23:07: Writing asset to /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/img/carousel
15: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {306} 2014-09-05 13:23:07: Asset destination full path: /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/img/carousel/1e50dc8.jpg
16: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {313} 2014-09-05 13:23:07: Writing asset to /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/img/carousel
17: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {306} 2014-09-05 13:23:07: Asset destination full path: /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/img/ddd6a55.png
18: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {313} 2014-09-05 13:23:07: Writing asset to /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/img
19: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {306} 2014-09-05 13:23:07: Asset destination full path: /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/img/ddd6a55.png
20: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {306} 2014-09-05 13:23:07: Asset destination full path: /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/img/ddd6a55.png
21: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {306} 2014-09-05 13:23:07: Asset destination full path: /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/img/ddd6a55.png
22: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {306} 2014-09-05 13:23:08: Asset destination full path: /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/js/libs/cbd6dfe.js
23: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {313} 2014-09-05 13:23:08: Writing asset to /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/js/libs
24: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {306} 2014-09-05 13:23:08: Asset destination full path: /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/js/bootstrap/08f5dfe.js
25: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {313} 2014-09-05 13:23:08: Writing asset to /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/js/bootstrap
26: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {306} 2014-09-05 13:23:08: Asset destination full path: /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/js/plugins/bootbox/e2f4d01.js
27: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {313} 2014-09-05 13:23:08: Writing asset to /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/js/plugins/bootbox
28: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {306} 2014-09-05 13:23:08: Asset destination full path: /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/js/6a12aee.js
29: DEBUG [AsseticAssetManager.php:processAsset()] {313} 2014-09-05 13:23:08: Writing asset to /var/www/html/thelia2/web/assets/frontOffice/default/0/js
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Are there any logs from your install?

Comment: Just posted the logs. I can't see anything helpful.

Answer (score 1):

the admin directory is not existing and will never exists. All those URL are virtual routes catched by a routing system inside Thelia.

For configuring Thelia, see the dedicated chapter of the documentation : http://doc.thelia.net/en/documentation/configuration.html

Comment: When everything is good, it should generate a 'admin' folder. I tried it on my own machine. The problem I got was on AWS. Anyway, I give up with it.

Comment: nop, the admin folder is never generated.

Maybe rewriting is not enabled on your machine ?